# Parse trailing initial from name

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a question on a string like Maria Johns K. . I want to separate the initial K. to one column and put the remaining in another column in PL/SQL.

Can someone help?

Comment: Please read : [How To Ask A Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: select REGEXP_SUBSTR('Maria Johns K.','[^ ]+$') from dual;

Comment: @Tejash----ORA-00980 well, but says "initial K.".

Comment: What is the pattern for finding the initials? can you please share some examples?

Comment: Some more examples would help. What is desired result if string looks like `Maria K. Johns` or `Maria K.` or `Maria Johns` or ...?

Comment: For all the case where Initial is one character with dot(.) at the end and space( ) before it, Following will work: `select TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR('Maria Johns K.','[ ][a-zA-Z]\.')) AS INITIALS from dual;` [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=97c31d2ffc40071fae274ae83a0d05dc)